# How to install Linux header files on a board running petalinux?

Tags: linux, header-files, petalinux

I just started using petalinux and yocto, and I'm now trying to start to write a MIPI driver.

My problem is that the petalinux running on my board doesn't have any Linux kernel header files, and neither the petalinux-create, petalinux-config, ... available.

Where can I find information about how to get the Linux header files and those petalinux tools installed? Also, will I need anything else installed to be able to write the MIPI driver?

Thanks!

Andre

Answer (score 1):

It turned out I needed add TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK += "kernel-devsrc" to the main bb file